# Using SMOTE-NC with categorical variables only

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, imbalanced-data, imblearn, smote

I am dealing with a dataframe containing only categorical features. To reproduce the issue I am facing I am going to make the following example:

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','c','a','c','c','c','c','c','c'],
     'col2':['a1','b1','c1','a1','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1'],
     'col3':[1,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I am going to split the data into test and train and take col3 as my target feature.

```
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
train_data = train_data.reset_index(drop=True)
test_data = test_data.reset_index(drop=True)

X_train = train_data.drop(['col3'], axis = 1)
X_test = test_data.drop(['col3'], axis = 1)
y_train = train_data["col3"]
y_test = test_data["col3"]
```

From X_train, col1 and col2 are my categorical features so index 0 and 1, hence I do SMOTE-NC as:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
cat_indx =[0,1]
sm = SMOTENC(categorical_features= cat_indx, random_state=0)
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

for which I get the following error:

```
ValueError: SMOTE-NC is not designed to work only with categorical features. It requires some numerical features.
```

I wonder how one does tackle this issue given the fact that SMOTE-NC is meant to be for handling the categorical variables? Also note that my target variable is multiclass and not binary, which I do not think causes any problem at this level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the very initials NC in the algorithm name mean *Nominal-Continuous*; as the error message clearly states, the algorithm is *not* designed to work with categorical (nominal) features only.

To see why this is so, you have to dig a little into the original [SMOTE paper](https://jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10302); quoting from the relevant [section](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/node15.html#SECTION00061000000000000000) (emphasis mine):

> While our SMOTE approach currently does **not** handle data sets with **all
> nominal features**, it was generalized to handle **mixed** datasets of
> **continuous and nominal features**. We call this approach Synthetic
> Minority Over-sampling TEchnique-Nominal Continuous [SMOTE-NC]. We
> tested this approach on the Adult dataset from the UCI repository. The
> SMOTE-NC algorithm is described below.
>
> 1. Median computation: Compute the median of standard deviations of all **continuous** features for the minority class. If the nominal
>    features differ between a sample and its potential nearest neighbors,
>    then this median is included in the Euclidean distance computation. We
>    use median to penalize the difference of nominal features by an amount
>    that is related to the typical difference in continuous feature
>    values.
> 2. Nearest neighbor computation: Compute the Euclidean distance between the feature vector for which k-nearest neighbors are being
>    identified (minority class sample) and the other feature vectors
>    (minority class samples) using the **continuous** feature space. For every
>    differing nominal feature between the considered feature vector and
>    its potential nearest-neighbor, include the median of the standard
>    deviations previously computed, in the Euclidean distance computation.

So, it is apparent that, in order for the algorithm to work, it needs **at least one continuous feature**. This is not the case here, so the algorithm rather unsurprisingly fails during step 1 (median computation), since there are not any continuous features to be used for the median computation.

Comment: Is there any resampling technique is there if there is only binary features are there in the whole dataset (both predictors and target) ?

Comment: @DOT I am not aware of any, sorry.